# Screen cap in Chrome measures bigger in Axure, why?

Tags: resolution, dpi, browser, axure

I'm putting together guidelines of graphic dimensions for our website. The sizes need to be exact. However, I noticed that there is a discrepancy between a shape in the browser, v.s. Axure. For example, a 1400*520PX box in Chrome becomes 1750x652.

I am guessing this might be due to my browser dpi resolution v.s. Axure canvas dpi resolution. Or am I completely off?

Could someone shed lights on this? How can I eliminate this discrepancy?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi lu yan, welcome to GD.SE! You inspected the image in the browser and it said that it was a different pixel size? When you view the properties on your computer, what does the pixel size say? Is it different than the browser and or what is in Axure? And what does Screen Cap mean?

Comment: 1400 to 1750 is exactly a 125% increase.  Do you have any system scaling set? Check your computer display settings.  If so, try switching it off.

Comment: sorry I got it flipped. The box I measured in browser is 1400 x 520, the downloaded image properties also confirm that. But once I pasted it into Axure, it became 1750 x 650.

Comment: @BillyKerr Oh my god, you are spot on. I checked my display, and had a 125% increase. I set it back to 100% and now it's all good. Thank you very much!

Comment: @luyan - you're welcome! glad that worked for you.

Comment: thanks @AndrewH